# jquery chosen not showing the selection option in dropdown

Tags: jquery-chosen

When jquery chosen's height is adjusted using the code

```
.chosen-results {
    height: 82px;
}
```

It does not calculates the height correctly and when u select options inside it using keyboard, options are not shown. How can I fix it?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/umcc9/6/

Steps:

```
1) Click on select box
2) Click Down key multiple times
3) When Val-4 will be highlight, it will not be visible in container
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Found the solution I need to set max-height

```
.chosen-results {
    max-height: 82px;
}
```